# Aurelia: Error: Unable to find module with ID: aurelia-pal-browser in Karma test with Webpack

Tags: webpack, karma-webpack, aurelia

I'm having an issue creating a test for an Aurelia component. In Karma debug the console shows:

`Error: Unable to find module with ID: aurelia-pal-browser` from aurelia-loader-webpack.

I'm using Webpack 4 and Karma 2.

I've tried the suggestions in [Debugging missing modules](https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/wiki/Debugging-missing-modules) but haven't any luck.

Anyone else come across this before?

## Karma config

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      './setup.js',
      '../src/**/*.js',
      './unit/**/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
      './setup.js': ['webpack'],
      '../src/**/*.js': ['webpack', 'coverage'],
      './unit/**/*.js': ['webpack']
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
    webpack: {
      mode: 'development',
      module: {
        rules: [{
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        }]
      }
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

## Aurelia test

```
import { StageComponent } from 'aurelia-testing';
import { bootstrap } from 'aurelia-bootstrapper';
import { PLATFORM } from 'aurelia-pal';

export class TestViewModel {
}

describe('cbs-toast tests', () => {
  let component;
  let viewModel;

  beforeEach(() => {
    viewModel = new TestViewModel();
    component = StageComponent
      .withResources(PLATFORM.moduleName('cbs-toast'))
      .inView('<div><toast></toast></div>')
      .boundTo(viewModel);
  });

  it('loads ok', done => {
    component.create(bootstrap).then(() => {
      done();
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e.toString());
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    component.dispose();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, most of the time if aurelia giving an error saying that "Unable to find module with ID", that's happening because of not using PLATFORM.moduleName() when we call a module. try to search the module name "aurelia-pal-browser" in your project and wrap it like below.
PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-pal-browser')

Comment: Problem is I'm not calling aurelia-pal-browser, the aurelia-webpack plugin is. Which is something I don't have control over.

Even their example here doesn't work:

https://aurelia.io/docs/testing/components#testing-a-custom-element

Comment: Can you put the same on following site
https://gitter.im/aurelia/Discuss?source=explore